# Why team sql is so slow to run queries?

Tags: teamsql

Why teamsql is so slow to execute sql commands? 
I've been using tableplus and teamsql clients and teamsql is to much slow than teable plus.

Answer (score 2):

If "QuerySense" is on for "All" or you're working on a production database (QuerySense is activated automatically), you can turn off "QuerySense" feature, it checks your queries and warns you if there is any DROP, DELETE, ALTER or similar SQL commands.

Since TeamSQL based on NodeJS (and also drivers) there are known performance issues, but drivers in TeamSQL 4.0 (still in beta) will be based on JDBC. You can try the beta version [here](https://teamsql.io/nightly).

You can turn off QuerySense in Preferences:
[image]